# invoke command string with named parameters gone wrong

Tags: powershell, cmd, parameter-passing, invoke-command

I want to execute a PowerShell script from Another server via `Invoke-Command`.

When I try it the response say that there is no parameter called vm. But there is in reality. Is it my string that is wrong?
The PowerShell script have 2 parameters: `vm` and `username`.

I have this string. Is it correct?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ******* -FilePath E:\blabla\blabla\transfer.ps1 -vm ***** -UserName ****
```

How do you use argument list to pass parameters into the script?

Comment: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName ******* -FilePath E:\blabla\blabla\transfer.ps1 -Argumentlist 'vm_input', 'username_input'`

Comment: `-vm ***** -UserName ****` would try to pass your arguments to `Inovke-Command` (which doesn't recognize these parameters) rather than to the script you want to invoke. Arguments to an invoked script or scriptblock must be passed via the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

Comment: Okej is this better? Invoke-Command -ComputerName ******** -FilePath E:\\blabla\\blabla\\transfer.ps1 -Argumentlist '****', '*****'

Comment: Don't ask us if the command looks okay. Try it and see if it works now. If it still fails, update your question with the modified command you ran. Include all errors you were getting.